# Replace string in a text file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using node.js. I want to read a file with some placeholder strings and replace them dynamically before I serve the file. This is not an HTML file, so a templating engine will not work.

How can I do this?

Comment: I've tried loading the file as a string and doing regex replace. Was wondering if there is a more elegant way though.

Comment: have you tried mustaches? http://mustache.github.com/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If a template engine is overkill just use `string.replace()`.

```
temp = "Hello %NAME%, would you like some %DRINK%?";

temp = temp.replace("%NAME%","Michael Dillon");
temp = temp.replace("%DRINK%","tea");
console.log(temp);
```

With only a bit more work you could make a general purpose template function based on just the standard methods in the String object.

Answer (score 2):

Templating engines are not only for html. If you are using Express, for instance, you can set your own headers and specify a content-type:

View:

```
var foo = "{{ bar }}";
```

Rendering:

```
app.get('/file.js', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('templateName', {
    locals: {bar: 'quux'},
    headers: {'content-type': 'text/javascript'}
  });
})
```

Will yield:

```
var foo = "quux";
```

If you are not using Express, you can just render the template and send the response with any content-type you like.