# Hiding some html block from anonymous users

Tags: html, node.js, authentication

How do I hide some html block from anonymous users who visit my application. I don't use any templating engine. My back end is in node.js .

What would be the best way to implement this?

```
if (loggedin) 

<div id="logged-in"> 
   Some menus for Loggedin User
</div>

else 
<div id="anonymous"> 
   Some menus for Anonymous user
</div>
```

Comment: You should use a templating engine.

Comment: Use a template engine, set a flag for logged in or not, and in the template file, simply check the flag.

Comment: Ok. Is there any work around without using one

Comment: There's no need to use a templating engine, but you'll need to use something to control what you output. Seeing some of your code would help.

Comment: We know what you mean, but a templating engine makes doing this as easy as the if/else statement you put in.  I recommend EJS, some like JADE.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a templating engine.

Should you not want to do that, you can build a function that reads whether or not the user is in a session, then either prints/includes a dynamic version of the HTML (header, body, div or whatever you need) with the user specific data for logged in users, or prints/includes a generic version of the HTML (header, body, div or whatever you need) for logged out users

Answer (score 1):

As others note, a templating engine is most likely the best choice. This is exactly the kind of problem they were designed to solve. Furthermore, introducing one now while the logic is simple will be less painful than introducing one later when an ad hoc solution becomes too cumbersome. (An ad hoc solution is probably going to be cumbersome to begin with, actually.)

However, one other potential solution would be to use 2 different HTML files and let your function choose which one to send the user based on whether they are logged in. This is only really feasible if the pages are completely different depending on the log in status. Even then, a templating engine allows for a more robust solution by including component files in the page, allowing you to share headers, footers, or any other common elements between the different pages.

If you are still against a templating engine and do not want to use different HTML files, you could basically do your own ad hoc templating. Put some kind of string to be replaced into the HTML, load the text into a string from the file, and use `string.replace` or something similar. A good example of `string.replace` is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5172295/1394393). If you choose to do this, be very careful that your "string to replace" does not conflict with HTML or any other languages used in the page itself.